# Get a list of indexes from checked listbox VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to get a list of indexes of items that are checked in my listbox eg.
    [x] one
    [] two
    [] three
    [x] four
would return 1,4
I would then like this list displayed in a listbox
Here is my code:

```
`Dim indexes As Integer()
indexes = CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Cast(Of Integer).ToArray()
For i = 1 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count
 ListBox2.Items.Add(indexes.Cast(Of Integer))
Next`
```

The error is that when I run it the listbox displays a string and not the actual number itself ie 1.
Any help appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
dim i as integer = 0
For Each TempItem  IN CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems 
    If Tempitem.checked then
       ListBox1.Items.Add(i.tostring)
    End If
    i+=1
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! How would I add this list to a list box ? Thanks

Comment: Depends on how you want to use it, but the easiest way is probably Listbox.Items.Add(<your string here>).....However, rather than creating an array of integers, if your purpose is to just get the values to a listbox, you can add them from inside the loop and do away with the array.

Comment: Thanks again! I just need the items in the list box so can do away with the array. What code would go in the loop to add them ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I edited the code....you may need to change the name of ListBox1 to whatever you named it.

Comment: Thank you so much, has really helped!

Comment: Hi, I have just tried your code, and got the following exception -                                             An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException'   occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Public member 'checked' on type 'String' not found.